# how to listen "android.intent.action.CAMERA_BUTTON" broadcast action in android device which do not have hardware camera button

Tags: android

how we can listen or receive  "android.intent.action.CAMERA_BUTTON" broadcast action in android device which do not have hardware camera button.

Comment: Do you mean "how can I simulate android.intent.action.CAMERA_BUTTON on devices which do not have camera button"? Because otherwise I'm not sure I understand the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't: the intent is only generated by the hardware camera button, not by the button within a camera app.