# Application is not receiving broadcast for camera being opened

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-camera

I want to receive a broadcast for camera being opened. I want to block that process if some condition is true.

I am not getting broadcast for camera being opened. (I can get broadcast for new picture taken, which is not what I want.)

This is a piece of my manifest file:

```
<receiver
            android:name=".HardwareActionListener"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="1000" >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.CAMERA_BUTTON" >
                </action>
            </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

This is a piece of my file HardwareActionListener.java

```
System.out.println("Intent action: " + intent.getAction());

if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(
                "android.intent.action.CAMERA_BUTTON")) {
            System.out.println("CAMERA Button broadcast received and aborted");
            if(some_condition_true)
                  abortBroadcast();
        }
```

I have searched on google and stackverflow for this for a whole day. And I tried each and every combination.
But I am not getting broadcast for camera being opened.

I am using Samsung Galaxy tab for testing. Which is not having hardware Camera button.

And one answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960663/how-to-listen-android-intent-action-camera-button-broadcast-action-in-android) says that

> You can't: the intent is only generated by the hardware camera button,
>   not by the button within a camera app.

So is there anything wrong in my manifest file's intent filter? Or is it the problem due to device not having hardware camera button?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to be notified when the default camera app is open ? Or when any app tries to access camera preview ? In any case the "android.intent.action.CAMERA_BUTTON" name is quite clear: you get notified when the physical camera button is pressed (if any)

Comment: When user tries to open a camera.

Comment: There are many ways camera can be "opened". I don't think you can be somehow notified when any app displays camera preview.

Comment: There is icon for camera application in device with all other applications. I want to block the user to open that camera

Comment: @MysticMagicϡ can you please briefly explain how did you do it using Device Policy Manager

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to receive a broadcast for camera being opened.

There is no such broadcast.

> I want to block that process if some condition is true.

Please use the device admin APIs to control access to the camera.

> This is a piece of my manifest file

You are listening for CAMERA button presses, which may or may not have anything to do with a camera app, and do not exist on all devices.

> But I am not getting broadcast for camera being opened.

That is because there is no such broadcast.

> And one answer in this question says that "You can't: the intent is only generated by the hardware camera button, not by the button within a camera app."

That answer is correct.

Comment: Thanks. Was able to do it using Device Policy Manager