# Observer CAMERA open event, not detect

Tags: android, camera, observers

I want to create an Observer for CAMERA in Android.
I know there is broadcast receiver for `com.android.camera.NEW_PICTURE`
But as it say it's for New Picture captured by camera. I want to observe camera if some one holding this CAMERA resource.

**Note: Not detecting camera use but observe it.**

Comment: I find a question close to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13452097/application-is-not-receiving-broadcast-for-camera-being-opened

Comment: @NguyễnHoàiNam I seen that question. Yes my question is similar to that question. But that question doesn't provide any solution. Hope some one will provide solution from core android source code which might be not documented.

Comment: By mentioning that Question, I meant that it's impossible to do what you want. If you really want to do that, you may need a higher level of access to the system (rooted devices, internal APIs ...) which is not encouraged.